# jsPDF always return Blank in particular Html file

Tags: javascript, pdf, html-table, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jsPDF autoTable to print pdf file, in my mproyect using Angular 7 works pretty fine in all html, but for some reason in one particular html file doesn't, it download the file but in a "Blank" mode, if attach an Image it print with success, here is the error:

```
jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:564 Html table could not be found with input:  tableGuias
```

It cannot find the html input declared, my question is why.

Any table that I try to create there does'nt work, here i'm creating a dummy one to show you.

```
<table id="tableGuias">
  <thead>
    <th>Dummy Header</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>Simple Test</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

now lets see the TypeScript file:

```
    getPdfFromHtml() {
      const  idTable = document.getElementById('tableGuias');
      const doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
      doc.autoTable( { html: idTable });
      setTimeout(function() {
          doc.save('tableGuias.pdf');
      }, 1000 );
    }
```

The component is well configured into @Component decorator, so Html and ts file are connected.
The setTimeout it's just because i've reading before that maybe could solve the problem, it was'nt my case.

Using getElementById() or getElementByClassName(), or just declare #table the tag table, did'nt work.

Cannot figured out what is happen. I've been thinking that some error could interrupt the method, but console does'nt throw no error apart from the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace:

```
doc.autoTable( { html: idTable });
```

with

```
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(idTable);
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);
```

to get the desired output.

**Demo:**

```js
function getPdfFromHtml() {
  const idTable = document.getElementById('tableGuias');
  const doc = new jsPDF('landscape');

  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(idTable);
  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);

  setTimeout(function() {
    doc.save('tableGuias.pdf');
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<!-- EDIT: For now, add this line between the libraries -->
<!-- The reason being that jspdf includes a version of requirejs which -->
<!-- jspdf-autotable currently is not expecting. You can also use version < 2.0.21 -->
<script>
  if (window.define) delete window.define.amd;
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.0.28/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>

<button onclick="getPdfFromHtml()">Download PDF</button>

<table id="tableGuias">
  <thead>
    <th>Dummy Header</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>Simple Test</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, you can use

```
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
```

option for a better-looking output for large tables like:

**Demo:**

```js
function getPdfFromHtml() {
  const idTable = document.getElementById('tableGuias');
  const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(idTable);
  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);

  setTimeout(function() {
    doc.save('tableGuias.pdf');
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<!-- EDIT: For now, add this line between the libraries -->
<!-- The reason being that jspdf includes a version of requirejs which -->
<!-- jspdf-autotable currently is not expecting. You can also use version < 2.0.21 -->
<script>
  if (window.define) delete window.define.amd;
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.0.28/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>

<button onclick="getPdfFromHtml()">Download PDF</button>

<table id="tableGuias">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris spécialités</td>
    <td>Marie Bertrand</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This answer it is a very good aproach i just tried to implement it, and some of objects could be printed, thank you, but for the complexity of my json is pretty much dificult to be mapped. i am going to continue for this way if i could acomplish with this way this will be the correct answer.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205255) to help future users too. Thanks!